# Pull out latest image from Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I need to pull out the last image uploaded by a specified user from their Facebook account.

I have permission of the user to do this. They basically want the last image they have uploaded to facebook, to be displayed on the front page of their site.

I'm not familiar with Facebook at all but I think I need to be looking at the graph api. Should I use Javascript or PHP for this? I need the quickest and most lightweight integration as we dont need to do anything else.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Photo methods](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) from the Graph API, which can be easily done using the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/). You'll also need to use the [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) routine, but before anything else, register an application on the [developers dashboard](http://facebook.com/developers).